# import xgboost in python causes error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I successfully installed xgboost but when I import it I get the problem as given below. I can't figure out the problem.

```
    >> import xgboost as xgb
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/home/deploy/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost/__init__.py", line 11, in <module> from 
    .core import DMatrix, Booster
    File "/home/deploy/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 112, in <module>
    _LIB = _load_lib()
    File "/home/deploy/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 106, in _load_lib
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])
    File "/home/deploy/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 425, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
    File "/home/deploy/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: /home/deploy/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so: invalid ELF header
```

Comment: A bit as in https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/463#issuecomment-147365960, a manual installation might succeed?

Comment: How did you install? @VonC most likely.

Comment: that would be the `sudo ./build.sh` part of the recipe mentioned in the link.

Comment: make command in the above link gives me this error

        `Makefile:29: dmlc-core/make/dmlc.mk: No such file or directory
        make: *** No rule to make target 'dmlc-core/make/dmlc.mk'.  Stop.`

Comment: I have exactly the same problem - have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Reinistalling as below fixed for me

```
conda remove xgboost

conda install py-xgboost
```